# is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django, json

I have the following ListView

```
import json
class CountryListView(ListView):
     model = Country

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):

         return json.dumps(self.get_queryset().values_list('code', flat=True))
```

But I get following error:

```
[u'ae', u'ag', u'ai', u'al', u'am', 
u'ao', u'ar', u'at', u'au', u'aw', 
u'az', u'ba', u'bb', u'bd', u'be', u'bg', 
u'bh', u'bl', u'bm', u'bn', '...(remaining elements truncated)...'] 
is not JSON serializable
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: What's **Country** model?

Comment: what is the traceback?

Comment: Does it work if you change the line to: `return json.dumps(list(self.get_queryset().values_list('code', flat=True)))`?

Comment: I get the `'str' object has no attribute 'status_code'` error, when add list

Comment: traceback is like `["ae", "ag", "ai", "al", "am", "ao", "ar", "at", "au", "aw", "az", "ba", "bb", "bd", "be", "bg", "bh", "bl", "bm", "bn", "bo", "bq", "br", "bs", "bt", "by", "bz", "ca", "ch", "ck", "cl", "cm", "cn", "co"]`

Comment: `return HttpResponse(json.dumps(self.get_queryset().values_list('code', flat=True)))` fixed the problem

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It's worth noting that the [`QuerySet.values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list) method doesn't actually return a list, but an object of type `django.db.models.query.ValuesListQuerySet`, in order to maintain Django's goal of lazy evaluation, i.e. the DB query required to generate the 'list' isn't actually performed until the object is evaluated.

Somewhat irritatingly, though, this object has a custom `__repr__` method which makes it look like a list when printed out, so it's not always obvious that the object isn't really a list.

The exception in the question is caused by the fact that custom objects cannot be serialized in JSON, so you'll have to convert it to a list first, with...

```
my_list = list(self.get_queryset().values_list('code', flat=True))
```

...then you can convert it to JSON with...

```
json_data = json.dumps(my_list)
```

You'll also have to place the resulting JSON data in an `HttpResponse` object, which, [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type), should have a `Content-Type` of `application/json`, with...

```
response = HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```

...which you can then return from your function.

Answer (score 2):

```
class CountryListView(ListView):
     model = Country

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):

         return HttpResponse(json.dumps(list(self.get_queryset().values_list('code', flat=True))),mimetype="application/json")
```

fixed the problem

also mimetype is important.