# json: TypeError: '<li>...spam...</li>' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, serialization

Within the following class I am trying to save some state information to a json file, however when I attempt to save a dictionary I come across a `TypeError: '<li>...stuff...</li>' is not JSON serializable`

```
class Save(object):
    def __init__(self, MainFrameDict):
        super(Save, self).__init__()
        self.MainFrameDict = MainFrameDict
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        self.writeJson()
    def writeJson(self):
        self.json_state_file = os.path.join(self.MainFrameDict['item_folder'],
                                            self.MainFrameDict['itemNumber']+'.json')
        with open(self.json_state_file,'wb') as f:
            json.dump(self.MainFrameDict['currentItemInfo'], f)
        self.printJsonStateFile()
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    def printJsonStateFile(self):
        with open(self.json_state_file,'rb') as f:
            json_data = json.loads(f)
```

Within the dictionary that I am trying to save:

```
(Pdb) print(self.MainFrameDict['currentItemInfo'].keys())
['image_list', 'description', 'specs']
(Pdb) print(self.MainFrameDict['currentItemInfo']['description'])
Run any time in the comfort of your own home. Deluxe treadmill
features 9 programs; plug in your MP3 player to rock your workout!
<ul>
<li>Horizon T101 deluxe treadmill</li>
<li>55" x 20" treadbelt</li>
<li>9┬áprograms</li>
<li>Fan</li>
<li>Motorized incline to 10%</li>
<li>Up to 10 mph</li>
<li>Surround speakers are compatible with your MP3 player (not
included)</li>
<li>71"L x 33"W x 55"H</li>
<li>Wheels for mobility</li>
<li>Folds for storage</li>
<li>Weight limit: 300 lbs.</li>
<li>Assembly required</li>
<li>Limited warranty</li>
<li>Made in USA</li>
</ul>
(Pdb) print type(self.MainFrameDict['currentItemInfo']['description'])
<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>
```

The traceback that I am trying to figure out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "display_image.py", line 242, in onNewItemButton
Save(MainFrame.__dict__)
  File "display_image.py", line 20, in __init__
self.writeJson()
  File "display_image.py", line 24, in writeJson
json.dump(self.MainFrameDict['currentItemInfo'], f)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 189, in dump
for chunk in iterable:
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 434, in _iterencode
for chunk in _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 408, in _iterencode_dict
for chunk in chunks:
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 442, in _iterencode
o = _default(o)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 184, in default
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: Run any time in the comfort of your own home. Deluxe treadmill
features 9 programs; plug in your MP3 player to rock your workout!
<ul>
<li>Horizon T101 deluxe treadmill</li>
<li>55" x 20" treadbelt</li>
<li>9┬áprograms</li>
<li>Fan</li>
<li>Motorized incline to 10%</li>
<li>Up to 10 mph</li>
<li>Surround speakers are compatible with your MP3 player (not
included)</li>
<li>71"L x 33"W x 55"H</li>
<li>Wheels for mobility</li>
<li>Folds for storage</li>
<li>Weight limit: 300 lbs.</li>
<li>Assembly required</li>
<li>Limited warranty</li>
<li>Made in USA</li>
</ul>
 is not JSON serializable
```

Docs/Posts looked at:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html
- [What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type?rq=1)
- [Python serializable objects json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458450/python-serializable-objects-json)
- [Python serializable objects json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458450/python-serializable-objects-json)
- [is not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336271/is-not-json-serializable)
- [Python sets are not json serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230315/python-sets-are-not-json-serializable)
- [Python serializable objects json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458450/python-serializable-objects-json)
- [How to overcome "datetime.datetime not JSON serializable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable-in-python)
- [JSON datetime between Python and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455580/json-datetime-between-python-and-javascript/2680060#2680060)
- [How to overcome "datetime.datetime not JSON serializable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable-in-python?lq=1)
- [JSON serialization of Google App Engine models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531501/json-serialization-of-google-app-engine-models?lq=1)

I am not sure if this is because it is nested, or if there is an issue with encoding/decoding. What exactly am I looking for and what am I not understanding? Is there a way to determine the encoding of an item?

Comment: what is the _type_ of `(self.MainFrameDict['currentItemInfo']['description'])`?  It's not a string, int, float, list, tuple, boolean or None, so json doesn't know what to do with it.  You'll need to convert it to one of those types...

Comment: Oh dang! `<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>` I didn't even. I'll just work on that. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect! If you move your comment to an answer, that solved it. So much to learn. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is the type of `self.MainFrameDict['currentItemInfo']['description']`?

It's not a `str`, `int`, `float`, `list`, `tuple`, `bool` or `None`, so `json` doesn't know what to do with it. You'll need to convert it to one of those types...

Comment: I had an error with the Mandrill API when passing a file argument to it.  With this answer, I wrapped the read() file in str(html_file), and it fixed this error. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. In case of me its work 100%. And can rncode into json any kind of python objects like dictionary, list, tuple etc or normal class object.

```python
import json

class DatetimeEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
   def default(self, obj):
       try:
        return super(DatetimeEncoder, obj).default(obj)
       except TypeError:
        return str(obj)


class JsonSerializable(object):
    def toJson(self):
        return json.dumps(self.__dict__, cls=DatetimeEncoder)

    def __repr__(self):
       return self.toJson()


class Utility(JsonSerializable):
     def __init__(self, result = object, error=False, message=''):
         self.result=result
         self.error=error
         self.message=message
```

At last call the Utility class like that .and convert to json

```
jsone = Utility()
jsone.result=result # any kind of object
json.error=True  # only  bool valu 
jsone.toJson()
```