# json response with python

Tags: python, json, django-1.7

i am using django 1.7.1,i got an error "is not JSON serializable".Here is my code

```
def Project_info(request):
        project_id=request.GET.get('project_id')
        people = Project_Management.objects.all().values()
        print people
        return returnSuccessShorcut ({'people': people })



def returnresponsejson(pass_dict, httpstatus=200):
    json_out = simplejson.dumps(pass_dict)
    return HttpResponse(json_out, status=httpstatus, content_type="application/json")


def returnSuccessShorcut(param_dict={}, httpstatus=200):
    param_dict['success'] = True
    return returnresponsejson(param_dict, httpstatus)
```

and console output is:-

```
[{'abbreviation': u'IOS', 'acid': None, 'end_date': datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 1, 4, 59, 59, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'start_date': datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 21, 5, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'user_story_id': None, 'project_name': u'2014 -KHL-347/Khaylo', 'modify_date': None, 'project_id': u'67375', 'user_name': None, 'id': 1L, 'isActive': None}]
```

But when I hit the api in browser I got the above error.
Kindly suggest the solutions.

Comment: which line in code gives the error?

Comment: in this line:-def returnSuccessShorcut(param_dict={},httpstatus=200):

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336271/is-not-json-serializable

Comment: Not related to your question, but in the line `def returnSuccessShorcut(param_dict={}, httpstatus=200):` you are using a dictionary as a default value for a parameter. Don't do that as any time you make use of the default the same dictionary will be shared between all calls to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert people to a list before serialize it, because `ValuesQuerySet` returned by [`QuerySet.values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) cannot be serialized by default.

```
def Project_info(request):
    project_id=request.GET.get('project_id')
    people = Project_Management.objects.all().values()
    people = list(people)
    return returnSuccessShorcut ({'people': people })
```

Comment: datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 1, 4, 59, 59, tzinfo=<UTC>) is not JSON serializable

Comment: @user3762689, In short: use `from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder; json_out = simplejson.dumps(pass_dict, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)`