# How to convert search query results into Json serializable object in Django

Tags: json, django, database

I am running a filter query in Django and my return results are as follows.

```
 search_result = [{'code': '12345', 'city': 'city1', 'country': 'USA', 'state': 'state1'}, {'code': '15675', 'city': 'city2', 'country': 'USA', 'state': 'state2'}]
```

I stored this returned data to a dictionary.

```
data_dict["return_result"] = search_result
data_dict["is_success"] = True
```

Now I am returning this data_dict as JsonResponse.(bcz this url was called using AJAX).

```
JsonResponse(data_dict)
```

In this process I am getting below error -

```
[{'code': '12345', 'city': 'city1', 'country': 'USA', 'state': 'state1'}, {'code': '15675', 'city': 'city2', 'country': 'USA', 'state': 'state2'}] is not JSON serializable.
```

Above mentioned data is a NOT a valid Json because of single quotes. If all single quotes are replaced with double quotes then this is a valid json.

Is there any way I can convert it to valid json or search query returns valid json.

Full Stack Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rana/DjangoProject/VirtualEnv/e/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/rana/DjangoProject/VirtualEnv/e/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/rana/DjangoProject/VirtualEnv/e/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rana/DjangoProject/Sanstha/sansthaonline/tenant/views/zip_city_search.py", line 37, in search_zip_city
    return JsonResponse(context)
  File "/home/rana/DjangoProject/VirtualEnv/e/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 505, in __init__
    data = json.dumps(data, cls=encoder, **json_dumps_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 237, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/encoder.py", line 192, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/encoder.py", line 250, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/home/rana/DjangoProject/VirtualEnv/e/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 115, in default
    return super(DjangoJSONEncoder, self).default(o)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/encoder.py", line 173, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: [{'city': 'city1', 'country': 'USA', 'code': '12345', 'state': 'state1'}, {'city': 'city2', 'country': 'USA', 'code': '15675', 'state': 'state2'}] is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is not JSON serializable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336271/is-not-json-serializable)

Comment: @Selcuk updated the question.

Comment: @Selcuk - as per my understanding, query return QuerySet type object which is not Json Serializable, but converting search_result to list convert the result into list type object, which is Json Serializable. Please comment if my understanding is not correct here.

Comment: You are right. You can either convert it to a list or use the special `DjangoJSONEncoder` as suggested in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you:-

```
import json
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

search_result = [{'code': '12345', 'city': 'city1', 'country': 'USA', 'state': 'state1'}, {'code': '15675', 'city': 'city2', 'country': 'USA', 'state': 'state2'}]


data = {'is_success':True,'msg':'Yor Success message','return_result':list(search_result)}

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data,cls=DjangoJSONEncoder),content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: converting search result to list worked very well. Is this standard way to do it or just a hack?
Could you please explain why your code works and my code dosn't work

Comment: your query result looks like you used `.values()` , have you? Try to use direct `.filter`, may be it works.