# Sending JSON data from view in Django

Tags: python, json, django

I have to store some data in the window object to use it un the frontend rendering. I have a model:

```
from django.db import models
from tools.various.db import Base
from tools.files.fields import CustomImgField, IMAGES_DIRECTORY_ORIGINAL
from django.conf import settings

class myModel(Base):
    myName                     = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='myName')
    mySurname                  = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='mySurname')
```

I have a view:

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.http import JsonResponse
from json import dumps
from front.models import Language
from front.models import myModel


class BaseView(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BaseView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['myData'] = myModel.objects.value()
        return context
```

And I want to retrieve `myData` as a JSON object and store it in `window` object:

```
  window.app = {
    data: {},
    settings: {
      staticUrl: '{{ STATIC_URL }}',
      urls: {},
      storedData: {{ myData|jsonify|safe }}
    }
  };
```

But I get this response:

```
[{'myName': u'foo', 'mySurname': u'bar', u'id': 1L, 'order': 0L}] is not JSON serializable
```

Does anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I just tried `return list(context)` as André Laszlo proposes: it returns

```
Exception Value: list indices must be integers, not str
```

But if I use:

```
    context['myData'] = list(myModel.objects.values())
    return context
```

It seems to work. I'm going to read the documentation about 'list()'.

Comment: What does `myModel.objects.value()` return? Do you have an `Order` model?

Comment: Hi Blurp, with `myModel.objects.value()` I get the same result, `[{'myName': u'foo', 'mySurname': u'bar', u'id': 1L, 'order': 0L}] is not JSON serializable`

Comment: Can you show the `value()` method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [<Django object > is not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790375/django-object-is-not-json-serializable)

Comment: Sorry, it is `values()`, not `value()`: `myModel.objects.values()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336271/is-not-json-serializable)

Comment: Yes, I have been reading those stackoverflow posts, but no results

Comment: What's this `jsonify` filter you're using?

Comment: `.values()` returns a `QuerySet` and it looks like your `jsonify` filter can't handle that. You might need to convert the value returned from `myModel.objects.values()` to a list first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning a python `dictionary`, you need to serialize it to JSON using `json.dumps()`

You are already importing `json` but not making use of it.

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.http import JsonResponse
from json import dumps
from front.models import Language
from front.models import myModel

class BaseView(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BaseView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['myData'] = myModel.objects.value()
        return dumps(context)
```

Additionally, you might want to read up on `ujson` - Faster than the builtin json library.

Preferably, if you are using Django 1.7+ you can do:

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.http import JsonResponse
from json import dumps
from front.models import Language
from front.models import myModel
from django.http import JsonResponse


class BaseView(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BaseView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['myData'] = myModel.objects.value()
        return JsonResponse(context)
```

Comment: Thank you alexis; with `context['myData'] = list(myModel.objects.values())` it works; it is better to use json.dumps()?

Comment: Well, it's odd that it works by doing it that way. Try my approach, if it works that way, use it. Using JsonResponse from django.http is the best approach.

Comment: Also because by using that, it sets the correct response headers, content-type: application/json for you. You can read about it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects

Comment: But, what if I have different contexts in my view, and I don't want to encode all of them? I imagine that if you apply `return JsonResponse (context)`you are encoding all of them.

Comment: You could then do ``return JsonResponse(context["ContextKey"])``

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But JSON serialization is quite fast, specially using ``ujson``

Comment: If you mean, you'd only like to encode ``dictionaries`` you could do: ``if isinstance(context,dict): return JsonResponse(context)``

Comment: `JsonResponse` doesn't make sense for this scenario. The question shows a template being rendered with a bit of JSON used to initialize the JavaScript on the page.

Comment: @NikitaSöze Please mark my answer as correct if it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is that your list is actually not a list, it's a QuerySet that just looks like a list when printed.

Have you tried:

```
context['myData'] = list(myModel.objects.values())
return context
```

I think it should return a list with dictionaries, which should be JSON serializeable. Please update your question with your results if it doesn't work.

Comment: Should be `context['myData'] = list(myModel.objects.values())`

Comment: Yes thank you, seems like OP got the idea at least :)